# How to count non zero elements in a vector and replace this values based the number of occurences

Tags: matlab

I'm a new matlab user and in my case i have a vector let say:

```
v = [0 0 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0.2]
```

I want to count consecutive non zero values i.e in my vector have first five nonzero values `[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5]` and two last nozeros values `[0.1 0.2]`

what I want is:
count the consecutive non zero values and put a condition i.e. if the length of nonzeros is greater then 3 (`count>3`) then the respective values of vector V(i) remain v(i) if the length consecutive values is less than three (`count<3`) then respective values of `v(i) = 0`

I want to get a new vector let say v1 derivated from vector v where:

```
v1 = [0 0 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox, you can use the power of morphological operations. The morphological *opening* ([`imopen`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html)) removes objects which are smaller than the structuring element from an image. We can use this in 2D and use `[1,1,1]` as structuring element to remove objects, i.e. sequences of nonzero elements, which are shorter than 3:

First we make the sequence binary: zero or nonzero.

```
w = v~=0;
```

Then we zero-pad the sequence, so short nonzero sequences at the borders get eliminated. As we use `[1,1,1]` as structuring element, zero-padding by 1 is sufficient:

```
w = [0,w,0];
```

Now we do the opening to remove all small nonzero sequences

```
w1 = imopen(w, [1,1,1]);
```

The vector `w1` now contains `0` if the corresponding element in `v` is or should be set to `0` and `1` if the value should be kept. To get the result `v1`, we can ignore the first and last entry (those are the elements from the zero-padding), and multiply that by the input, as e.g. `1 * 0.1 = 0.1`:

```
v1 = w1(2:end-1) .* v;
```

Which gives the correct result *without* any for loop, if statement or such stuff!  Only 4 simple operations: morphology and a bit of multiplication and zero-padding.

Comment: Thank you answer.  From this solution i got this error:  Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in TESTHeatLossCalcDHWCatoffShortDraw (line 108)
w = [0,w,0];

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer=0 %Buffer to remember non zero values
v=[0 0 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0.2];
v1=[];

for i=1:length(v)
    if v(i)~=0 
        buffer=buffer+1; 
        v1(i)=v(i);
    end
    if v(i)==0
        switch buffer
            case 1 % case 1 corresponds to only 1 non zero value in a single sequence
                v1(i-1)=0;
                buffer=0;
            case 2 % case 2 corresponds to only 2 non zero value in a single sequence

                v1(i-1)=0;
                v1(i-2)=0;
                buffer=0;
            otherwise
                buffer=0;
        end
    end

end

switch buffer  % Test for the last two values
    case 1
        v1(length(v))=0;
    case 2
        v1(length(v))=0;
        v1(length(v)-1)=0;
end
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The code seem s to work Ok. Just wonder how if the logical expression: if v(i)==0  find values in the vector that are zero then how is possible that this work in the loop to switch cases 1 and 2 that from you comments  corresponds to only non zero value in a sequence ??

Comment: The switch is associated with the buffer : The buffer will stay at 0 if the previous value is equal to 0 (it went to the case "otherwise" during the previous case for the 'if'). The buffer will be equal to 1 or 2 if the previous values were not equal to 0. Say you have 2 values non equal to 0, the 'if' will increment the buffer two times. So when you check the third value, which is 0, the code will check the buffer, and as it is equals to 2, it knows that the previous series of values non-equal to 0 was composed of only 2 data, and so it will replace them both by 0.

Comment: If your previous non-zero data was 3 data long or larger, the switch will also go in the 'otherwise' case, which resets to 0 the buffer and does not modify the values. I hope it makes sense to you, if you're new to matlab that solution should not be too complex.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation however not quiet understood. In my understanding "buffer" in the loop at the logical condition: "if v(i)==0 should deal only with the zero values meanwhile from your comment: case 1 "case 1 corresponds to only 1 non zero value in a single sequence it sounds that is dealing with nonzero values".  If the condition is If v(i)==0 then how the loop find the nonzero 1 and 2 consecutive values ?       i'm missing this steep.

Comment: The buffer has nothing to do with the `if` condition. Just think of the buffer as a way to check that the series of non-zero values before the zero value you're testing with the `if` is longer than 2.

Comment: Thank you, now it make sense to me.